# Does weapon proficiency grant a bonus to attack AND damage?

Tags: dnd-4e

Rolling a 1st level Dwarf Knight (from Hero of the Fallen Lands). He has a strength of 18 so a str mod of +4. I've calculated the Attack Bonus as (**+4** *str mod*.) + (**+3** *weap. prof* from longsword) = **+7**

My question is - How does the Damage work for this? (basic melee). Do I add the weapon proficiency bonus to the damage as well? ie. **1d8+7** ? or, is it simply **1d8+4** (using the str modifier only)

Comment: Welcome to the site. You're right, Wizards could have phrased it better.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**A weapon's proficiency bonus adds only to accuracy.**

With your 18 strength, +4 strength modifier and longsword, your attack is:

`+7 versus AC // 1d8+4 damage`

A 2[W] attack with your longsword would then be:

`+7 versus AC // 2d8+4 damage`

At higher levels, you add half your level to your accuracy, but *not* your damage. At level 11, then, with a 22 (+6) strength, +3 magic longsword, your attack would be:

(+6 strmod +3 proficiency +3 enchantment + 5 half-level) =

`+17 versus AC // 1d8+9 damage.`

Comment: excellent, I thought this was the case but thanks for clearing it up.